# Pass info from Parent View to Child ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, prism

I have in my ParentView(DashboardConsultants) a gridview which shows a custom tooltip when the user's mousepointer is hovered over a cell. The tooltip show a View (AgreementDetails_View) which shows information of the Agreement binded to that cell. I will show the code I have now so you can better understand my question:

DataGrid Cell in ParentView:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Okt" Width="*" x:Name="test">
    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
       <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">                                   
            <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding Months[9].AgreementID}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="DataGridCell.ToolTip" >
                <Setter.Value>
                     <v:UC1001_AgreementDetails_View Background="#FFF" Opacity="0.88"  />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
```

My ChildView:

```
 public UC1001_DashBoardConsultants_View(UC1001_DashboardConsultantViewModel viewModel)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = viewModel;
        }
```

In the ViewModel, I have following method to get the right Agreement from the database:

```
 private void GetRefData()
        {
            UC1001_ActiveAgreementArguments args = new UC1001_ActiveAgreementArguments();
            args.AgreementID = 3;
            DefaultCacheProvider defaultCacheProvider = new DefaultCacheProvider();
            if (!defaultCacheProvider.IsSet("AgrDet:" + args.AgreementID))
            {
                ConsultantServiceClient client = new ConsultantServiceClient();

                AgreementDetailsContract = client.GetAgreementDetailsByAgreementID(args);
                defaultCacheProvider.Set("AgrDet:" + args.AgreementID, AgreementDetailsContract, 5);
            }
            else
            {
                AgreementDetailsContract = (UC1001_ActiveAgreementContract)defaultCacheProvider.Get("AgrDet:" + args.AgreementID);
            }
        }
```

As you can see for now, the method always calls the same Agreement, (I did that for testing purposes) but now I want the Agreement which ID is specified in the DataGrid Cell Tag (in this example it's the `Months[9].AgreementID`).

I can give it to the ViewModel in my Child View's constructor, but I don't think that it's allowed due to the MVVM Pattern (or is it allowed?).

So my question is: How can I pass the AgreementID specified in my ParentView to the ChildView's ViewModel to get the right data for the ChildView?

Ofcourse, more information/code/clarification can be happily provided, just ask :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that I got question in righ way but my feelings like you need to use Commands instead of introducing tied coupling by passing back reference to parent itself

Comment: I also thought of Commands but I can't define a command in the Tooltip property (where I can call the Month[].AgreementID) or do you suggest placing the Command somewhere else?

Comment: The question is why Parent View show details of agreement? Why is not AgreementView does this (which actually bound with AgreementViewModel whcih has a reference to udnerlying Agreement)?

Comment: What do you mean? The ParentView has a gridd and each cell contains an AgreementID. When I hover over the cell, it shows a tooltip of a View which contains more information of that Agreement (not just the AgreementID)

Comment: So each cell can represent a single AgreementView, and in DataContext of AgreementView should be AgreementViewModel which exposes all Agreement properties. This would be MVVM

Comment: Does following make any sense from business logic perspectives -DashboardConsultantsViewModel has a List of AgreementViewModels?

Comment: No, DashBoardConsultantsViewModel has a list of Months, and each month has as AgreementID attached to it, like the Months[9].AgreementID example in my question.

Comment: @Jelle Capenberghs : what is Month entity? Perhaps it makes sense to keep Agreements which of then has own associated Month value?

Comment: Month is an entity (WCF Contract in this case) which holds a color to show as the cell background color, and an AgreementID to have as value to show the Agreement in the Child View. If I understand correctly, what you suggest is to keep the whole Agreement in de Month entity instead of only the AgreementID? If I keep the whole Agreement in the Month entity, wouldn't that be bad for the performance of the application?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I feel that WPF Views should be nothing more than a pretty reflection of the `ViewModel`. So the `View` should not actually be passing any data to the `ViewModels` - instead it should be reflecting the ViewModel's data.

In your case, I would attach a property to the object that is displayed in each DataGrid Row. For example, if your DataGrid contained `Agreement` objects, I would ensure that each `Agreement` object had a property called `AgreementDetails` which can be viewed from the `ToolTip`

Comment: The Parent ViewModel doesn't have Agreement Objects, only objects with the ID, like the Month[9].AgreementID in the example in my question

Comment: @JelleCapenberghs What is your DataGrid bound to?

Comment: The ItemsSource of the DataGrid is bound to a Model (in my case a WCF contract) which contains some information about the Consultant of an Agreement, the status of the current month, and a list of contracts containing information of all the months

Comment: @JelleCapenberghs So it's not a Collection? I was thinking your View was bound to your `ViewModel`, and the `DataGrid` was bound to the list of `Contacts`. From there, each `Contact` would have an `AgreementDetails` property

Comment: I'm sorry, it's an ObservableCollection of the WCF contract. With Contact I assume you mean the WCF contract? So you suggest putting the whole Agreement in the WCF Contract instead of only the AgreementID? Isn't that harmful to the performance of the application?

Comment: @JelleCapenberghs It depends on how long it takes for you Agreement data to load. If it's quick, you could pass it in with the WCF Contract, or if its slow you could lazy-load it when needed in the `set` method

Answer (score 0):

It's pefectly legal and valid to pass in that ID eitehr via a constructor or through a property. I'm not sure from your code, but if your parent is the one with access to your model, you can also pass teh model into your view model (i.e. via constructor, property, or method).

One thing I often do in this case is to add a property such as the following in the ViewModel of my Parent:

```
object ActiveItem {get;set;}
```

I then bind that ActiveItem to the ActiveItem in my grid.

```
<DataGrid SelectedItem="{Binding ActiveItem}">
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: So you suggest binding the ID to the ParentViewModel, then pass it to the ChildViewModel, which passes the right information to the ChildView? That makes sense, how do I bind the active DataGrid Cell (with its ID) to the ActiveItem property?

Comment: Assuming this is the default WPF datagrid you are talking about, you can bind the ActiveItem property in your ViewModel to the [SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem.aspx) property on the grid

Comment: The ToolTip shows when I hover over the cell, not when I select it (click on it), does it still work then with the SelectedItem binding?